# Is it possible to render / project / flatten a 3d model onto a 2d plane in Unity?

Tags: unity

If I have a 3d Object (character) could I use a renderer / shader / camera mode to essentially render the 3d object as a 2d sprite?

Not looking for a full tutorial on this one, I realize its a large question; just looking for a direction to head in.

My thought on this one is that it would be easier to create a 3d model and move it to a position for a book-style game. The character could be posed in a number of different positions. I'd add some sort of outline and Cel shader and outline to get the affect, but in order to get it to view properly on my otherwise 2d game, I would need it to be in a panel or something that could have a "Sorting Layer" added to it.

Comment: Can you describe what attributes of a 2D sprite you want? Anytime we draw a model to a screen or a texture, we're effectively creating a 2D view of it. If that's all you need, then this is very easy. But if you want other effects, like being able to stack 3D models and order them like they're flat cards, or apply "sprite space" effects to them, then the solutions can get a little trickier. Want to edit your question to show us an example of what you're trying to accomplish? That can help us find solutions that achieve that goal.

Comment: You made a good point... I've edited my question. Essentially yes... what if I wanted to have a 3d hero on a "playing card" and then animate him while keeping his "2d"ness? I have been watching videos on "Toon Shaders" and I assume if I apply that with a thick outline, that might help, but what about sorting / other 2d things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out RenderTextures. These are 2D textures that you can display on models / sprites or in the UI, but that you can also render into, changing their contents on the fly.

You can create a new render texture with a fixed resolution and format in your Assets folder, or construct one in script if you need to have a flexible resolution at runtime (say, based on the user's display size or quality settings)

The Camera component has a Target parameter you can set to point at a Render Texture, so that whatever the camera sees gets drawn into the texture, instead of onto the screen. Use this in conjunction with Layers and layer masks on the cameras, so that only this to-texture camera can see your 3D model, and other cameras don't try to render it.

Now you can use this render texture as the texture for any material in your game (including a sprite material, or you can make a sprite from a region of the render texture), or supply it to a RawImage component in the UI to draw it as part of a menu.

Comment: I've attempted this, and while I cannot get it to work, I believe this is the correct answer. I'm not sure that you can use a RenderTexture on a sprite though (https://forum.unity.com/threads/render-texture-on-2d-sprite.496317/) I may have to use a quad or RawImage.

Comment: You can copy a RenderTexture's contents into a Texture2D to then pass to Sprite.Create, [as shown here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/convert-existing-rendertexture-for-a-spritesheet.386911/). If you ran into any specific obstacle making it work, please edit your question to clarify where you're stuck so we can help you overcome it.